# So I want to convert a Object into a String, but it should be a complete plain string with absolutely no ' " ', or " , " or " : "

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, type-conversion

Ok So For Example let's say this is My Object.

```
const myObj = {
   cf_retryAttempts:0,
   cf_amount:1,
   cf_event:"SUBSCRIPTION_NEW_PAYMENT",
   cf_eventTime:"2022-01-10 10:03:50",
   cf_paymentId:1,
   cf_referenceId:2,
   cf_subReferenceId:3,
}
```

If I use JSON.stringify(myObj) it returns something like `{"cf_retryAttempts":"0"...}` But I don't want that what I want is a complete string without any doubleQuotes, commas or colon separators between key value. so what I'm expecting is something like:

```
const string = cf_amount1cf_eventSUBSCRIPTION_NEW_PAYMENTcf_eventTime2022-01-10 10:51:02cf_paymentId1cf_referenceId2cf_retryAttempts0cf_subReferenceId3
```

If you want to understand more please check the docs as to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Link: https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/webhooks-1#verify-signature

Language: JS

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate all its keys and values, also recursively if you encounter an object.

```js
const myObj = {
  cf_retryAttempts: 0,
  cf_amount: 1,
  cf_event: "SUBSCRIPTION_NEW_PAYMENT",
  cf_eventTime: "2022-01-10 10:03:50",
  cf_paymentId: 1,
  cf_referenceId: 2,
  cf_subReferenceId: 3,
  cf_inner: {
    'this': 'that'
  }
}

function iterate(obj) {
  var result = ""
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(function([key, value]) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
      result += (key + iterate(value))
    } else {
      result += (key + value)
    }
  })
  return result;
}
console.log(iterate(myObj))
```

Answer (score 0):

simply ?
`cf_` elements are sorted.

```js
const myObj = 
  { cf_retryAttempts  : 0
  , cf_amount         : 1
  , cf_event          : 'SUBSCRIPTION_NEW_PAYMENT'
  , cf_eventTime      : '2022-01-10 10:03:50'
  , cf_paymentId      : 1
  , cf_referenceId    : 2
  , cf_subReferenceId : 3
  , signature         : 'tT9pXZkT2LuDzXacYDUaur7EX3dJgNKcITHQng44tns='
  } 

function objStr( {signature, ...cf_x })
  {
  return Object.entries(cf_x)
    .sort((a,b)=>a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
    .reduce((r,[e,k])=> r+e+k,'')
  }
 
console.log( objStr(myObj) )
```